# Changing label text with visual basic.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, label

I have an array to translate "hello" and I want to the label text each time I click a button. I hope this makes sense I am new to VB and a novice programmer.

```
Private Sub langChangeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles langChangeBtn.Click
    Dim helloArray() As String = {"Hola", "Ni hao!", "Hallo!", "Kon'nichiwa!", "Shalom!"}

    For i As Integer = 0 To helloArray.Length - 1

        lblHello.Text = helloArray(i)

    Next
End Sub
```

Right now it displays the last item in the array. Thanks in advance

Comment: It displays them all - just too quickly for you to notice.  If you want it to display one for each click dont loop thru them all.

Comment: You could add a Timer to your form and change the text in the label each time the Timer ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, you will display "next" "hello" with every click of the button

```
Private _currentHello As Integer = 0
Private _helloArray() As String = {"Hola", "Ni hao!", "Hallo!", "Kon'nichiwa!", "Shalom!"}


Private Sub langChangeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles langChangeBtn.Click


    lblHello.Text = helloArray(_currentHello)
    _currentHello += 1
    If _currentHello = helloArray.Length Then _currentHello = 0

End Sub
```

This should do it